# Rails 3 to 4 migration uniqueness validation issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec

## Context

We are migrating from Rails 3.2.12 to 4.0.2 and Ruby 1.9.3 to 2.1.8.

We have a lot of test coverage to accomplish the migration in the form of RSpec.

## Issue

One of the spec that checks that a uniqueness validation on a Card model is failing.

```
validates :mobile, uniqueness: {scope: :program_member_id, message: I18n.t('models.card.error.cardholder_already_has_mobile')}, if: :mobile
```

Where a `program_member` may only have one `mobile: true` card.

The spec creates 2 cards for the member, turns one into a mobile card, then expects the validation's message when doing so with the second card.

```
let(:program) { FactoryGirl.create(:program) }
let(:card) { FactoryGirl.create(:card, program: program) }

context 'when cardholder already has a mobile card' do
  it 'fails validation' do
    card2 = FactoryGirl.create(:card, program: program)
    program_member_user = FactoryGirl.create(:program_member_user, card_number: card2.cardnumber)
    program_member = program_member_user.program_members.first

    program_member.cards << card2
    card2.update_attributes(:mobile => true)

    program_member.cards << card
    card.update_attributes(:mobile => true)

    expect(card.errors.messages).to include(:mobile=>[I18n.t('models.card.error.cardholder_already_has_mobile')])
  end
end
```

Expectation:

```
expected {} to include {:mobile=>["Cardholder already has a mobile card"]}
```

When I go to our `master` branch, this spec passes.

The only factor that has changed from this spec working to failing is the Rails 3 to 4 migration.

Tried running the spec code in console only to find the member has 2 mobile cards and doing `card.valid?` returns `true` for both instances.

## Question

Has anything changed in Rails 4 in regards to uniqueness validation or validation life cycle?

Comment: Would you mind sharing what `register_card` does for completeness?

Comment: @JanKlimo I've updated the question to reflect the actual code being executed for assigning the card to a program_member_user. Even when I add everything manually in console, I still cannot get the validation to work. Even removing the condition of the validation has no effect (that is, doing the validation for uniqueness for non-mobile cards).

Comment: Hmm, very strange since I don't see any problem with your code. I created a test repo with a simplified version of your problem but identical validation. If you clone it and run rspec, does the test pass? https://github.com/janklimo/TestUniquenessApp

Comment: @JanKlimo your repo has some issues like uncertain Ruby version and Rails is at 4.2.7. I've created my own repo and I'm getting the same issue with the same-ish code. Here is the repo link: https://github.com/frank184/test_uniquness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I'm onto something.

I created a test project using the same Ruby and Rails version.

https://github.com/frank184/test_uniquness

In this project, I would have a `User` model that has an `admin` column as a boolean with a similar validation.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :admin, if: :admin?
```

I used shoulda-matchers and rspec to describe the desired outcome.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  let(:user) { build :user }
  subject { user }

  describe 'validations' do
    context 'when admin = true' do
      before(:each) { user.admin = true }
      it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:admin)  }
    end
  end
end
```

The spec failed with the following output:

```
Failures:

  1) User validations when admin = true should validate that :admin is case-sensitively unique
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:admin)  }

       User did not properly validate that :admin is case-sensitively unique.
         After taking the given User, whose :admin is ‹true›, and saving it as
         the existing record, then making a new User and setting its :admin to
         ‹true› as well, the matcher expected the new User to be invalid, but
         it was valid instead.
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:10:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.11435 seconds (files took 0.79997 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

I decided that the code was good and bumped Rails to 4.1.0 exactly.

The spec passed!

```
bundle update
rspec
.

Finished in 0.09538 seconds (files took 1.28 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: Mind that `is_expected` works on the `subject` so you should replace `user` in your specs with `subject` and see if it still works.

Comment: Look above `describe 'validations' do`.

Comment: So you're doing just fine. Add your solution to an answer and accept it so it can help other people. :)

Comment: make sure that uniqueness is a DB restriction and  a validation. Only both together provide real uniqueness in production.

Comment: @KcUS_unico this is not the case for conditional validation, where we do not want validation unless the column is true. Meaning, users may have many cards (mobile false), but only one mobile card.